# Cache jQuery Objects - Radio Button

Tags: jquery, variables, radio-button

I am caching my objects in Jquery variable and using that variable to perform operations . I am not getting the correct syntax to get the value of checked radio button using this approach

Example

```
var genderVar=$('input:radio[name=sex]');
```

gets the radio button reference to my genderVar . To check whether the button is checked or not using genderVar the following approach works

```
genderVar.is(':checked')
```

Could you please let me know how to get the checked value using genderVar ?  ( I know using direct approach `$('input:radio[name=bar]:checked').val();` ) but want the way to get the value using cached object .I tried the below , but didn't work ...

```
genderVar(':checked').val();
```

Thanks and Regards

Kiran

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use:
    $(genderVar+':checked').val()

Comment: Thanks Chris for your help and quick response . That resolved my issue .

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new selector pulling your old selector with jQuery's internal `selector` property and then adding `:checked`:

```
$(genderVar.selector + ':checked').val();
```

[Example →](http://jsfiddle.net/Gef4P/1/)